# Programmatically create new post from a metabox button

Tags: metabox, forms, wp-insert-post

Given a classic course-lesson structure, created by custom post types, I want to add a new empty lesson for a course, by using a simple html form on a metabox, in the course edit screen.

I think I understand the basis for execute a function in response to a GET (or POST) action on a html form, and indeed the  new lesson is created if I build the proper URL on the browser address bar, or if I put the html form in a template page. But when I move the same html form to the metabox and push the submit button, I just get a redirection to the post list admin page, and the function for create a new lesson is not executed.

Any clue about what is going wrong?

I'm learning, and I'm writting this code on a code snippet, using Code Snippets plugin (I think it is equivalent to write the code to the functions.php file of the theme).

Thank you very much!

```
// Add metabox to "bdg_course" CPT
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() { 
   add_meta_box('bdg_add_lesson', 'Add lesson', 'bdg_new_empty_lesson_form', 
'bdg_course', 'side');
});

// Callback function to fill metabox with html form
function bdg_new_empty_lesson_form() { 
?>
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" 
method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="foobar">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
 <?php
}

// Let's use admin_post_foobar hook to execute a form handler function every 
// time somebody sends the form
add_action('admin_post_foobar', 'programmatically_create_lesson');

// Form handler function
function programmatically_create_lesson() {
 wp_insert_post(
        array(                
            'post_title'        =>  $_GET["title"],               
            'post_type'         =>  'bdg_lesson'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: when you are on the edition page of a post, all metaboxes are already inside a tag "form". then you cannot output another form, having nested forms is not allowed by HTML. another solution for the lesson creation can be the use of an AJAX call.

Comment: Ok, thank you for pointing it out, mmm. That was why it was not working as I expected.